# radio play about crosstime-traveling bidet advertiser

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, radio-play

Thirty-odd years ago I heard a radio play about someone finding himself in a parallel world, very similar to his own, except that no one has ever heard of his fabulously successful advertising campaign “Where's the bidet?”

I think it was a British production. I don't know whether it was new or old at the time. Coincidentally or not, right about when I heard it, Wendy's launched the “Where's the beef?” campaign.

Comment: For some reason I misread this as "*cross-dressing time travel adviser*".